# Springboot and IDEA error: Could not autowire. No beans of 'EntityLinks' type found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am following Spring in action 5th edition to learn Springboot. When I am in chapter 6, I find that my IDEA IDE seems to have a bug for bean org.springframework.hateoas.server.EntityLinks.

```java
package tech.enigma.web.api;

import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.EntityLinks;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import tech.enigma.Taco;
import tech.enigma.data.TacoRepository;


@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/design", produces = "application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class DesignTacoController
{
    private TacoRepository tacoRepo;
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    public DesignTacoController(TacoRepository tacoRepo, EntityLinks entitylinks)
    {
        this.tacoRepo = tacoRepo;
        this.entityLinks = entitylinks;
    }

    @GetMapping("/recent")
    public Iterable<Taco> recentTacos()
    {
        PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(
                0, 12, Sort.by("createAt").descending());

        return tacoRepo.findAll(page).getContent();
    }
}
```

At public DesignTacoController(TacoRepository tacoRepo, EntityLinks entitylinks) Constructor, IDEA gives an error "Could not autowire. No beans of 'EntityLinks' type found." I can compile and run my program although I am not sure it works properly.
Other beans all works ok.
Is this just a bug of IDEA or I got something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243044). IntelliJ will not always pickup all available beans due to incorrect scanning of autoconfigured resources.
What counts is the Spring runtime. If it doesn't result in an error, you are good to go.

Comment: thanks, I wonder why this hard to solve since I saw similar problem on stack overflow posted three years ago

Comment: IntelliJ needs to index available beans. It’s hard to know what will be in scope based on a specific annotation. If a library even changes those annotations it will break. If you don’t know the annotation it will break. If it’s based on libs on the classpath which intellij doesn’t know yet it will break. It needs to simulate all of that without starting the spring runtime.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired  annotation is missing. Either do constructor injection or setter injection then it will work.

```
package tech.enigma.web.api;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.EntityLinks;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import tech.enigma.Taco;
import tech.enigma.data.TacoRepository;


@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/design", produces = "application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class DesignTacoController
{
    @Autowired
    private TacoRepository tacoRepo;
    @Autowired
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

   

    @GetMapping("/recent")
    public Iterable<Taco> recentTacos()
    {
        PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(
                0, 12, Sort.by("createAt").descending());

        return tacoRepo.findAll(page).getContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Autowired is optional since Spring 4.3 if there's only one constructor

Comment: I have tried all three methods, however the result is same.